# Is there any way to stream ubuntu one cloud music to xbox 360?

Tags: ubuntu-one, stream, xbox-360

I want to listen to the music I uploaded to my ubuntu one music account on my xbox 360. The windows streaming is ok, but it doesn't always work.

Comment: I don't think we currently have any plans for anything native on the 360, but it might be possible to get something working using the UPnP support built into the console (the same feature used for streaming from Windows Media Player).  While it isn't a polished solution I do have a prototype that I've been testing to stream to other UPnP media players but haven't tested against the Xbox.  I can provide you some details on how to test it if you're interested.  Alternatively, since this requires an Ubuntu computer I can provide an answer on how to stream from local files.

Answer (score 2):

At this time, there is no native support for streaming. You may be able to find some sort of homebrew app or API that can help you stream. A temporary solution may be to just burn the music to a CD-R and put it in you Xbox. This will launch a process that allows you to save the music onto the HDD. The benefit to this is the ability to listen to music whilst playing a game, which is currently impossible to do with streaming alone (on the Xbox, anyway).